# Can't backup broken iPhone 6 without entering pin

Tags: iphone, backup

I have recently broken the screen on my iPhone 6 and want to back everything up before I take it into apple to be repaired.

My problem is when I go to back the phone up in iTunes, it wants my pincode. I can't put my pincode in as my screen is broken!

The screen seems to be responding to key presses as it vibrates when I touch the screen where I think the numbers are, but this still doesn't work.

Does anyone know a way I can get a backup of my phone despite this issue?

Comment: I would put this as an answer but I don't have a iPhone6 to make the relevant image.  You could try and get an image of the passcode screen for an iPhone 6. and print it at the exact size for the phone. Cut out the number buttons and then lay the image on the screen. You should then have a template that you can touch the right spaces for the numbers.

Comment: Did you have iCloud backup enabled?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, entering the pass code is a security feature when you backup for the first time to a different iTunes/computer. You can't get around it, however its possible that Apple will be able to repair the screen without wiping the phone. Maybe even mention you haven't backed up the phone when you take it to get repaired and see if they can do anything for you

Answer (score 0):

Logic board works but no display, in other words the phone works but there is no way for you to see whats going on on it. My best suggestion its to take this phone to repair to a local phone repair shop. that way you get the same phone back and they don't need to reset the phone for any reason, unless you consent. The key here is not to loose that logic board which is the one that contains all the info, files that you wanted to back up. Apple will just process your phone as any other and they will replace for a another of same kind just like phone insurances.

Answer (score 0):

If you have previously synced your iPhone to iTunes, it should automatically sync your device (with 'Sync' button). This creates a backup of everything on your phone. So in case you did the backup previously on the different computer, try connecting to it. You should see some files by browsing the devices (audio/video recording, apps, etc.). In case you just need to backup the pictures, try to run *Photos* or *Picasa* app instead, you should be able to import these pictures directly from there. Then after you're happy with the sync and backup, you should consider restoring the device from the previous backup in the [recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201263).

See also the following steps depends on your circumstances:

- [How to unlock your iPhone passcode if you have previously synced your iPhone to iTunes](https://www.netchimp.co.uk/webdesign/iphone-ipad-macbook-mac/how-do-you-unlock-an-iphone-if-you-forgot-your-passcode#sync)
- [How to unlock your iPhone passcode if you have never synced your iPhone to iTunes](http://www.netchimp.co.uk/webdesign/iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-tips/unlock-iphone-forgot-passcode-synced-itunes/#neversync)
- [How to unlock your iPhone passcode if you don’t have access to a computer](https://www.netchimp.co.uk/webdesign/iphone-ipad-macbook-mac/unlock-iphone-forgot-passcode-computer/#nocomputer)