# Frozen touchpad on iphone 6 having a passcode

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to get into your iphone 6 when

1. the touchpad is not working and
2. I have set a passcode so, doing anything with the phone (like a reset) needs logging in first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't backup broken iPhone 6 without entering pin](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176454/cant-backup-broken-iphone-6-without-entering-pin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Doing a [force restart](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201559) might take care of frozen screen.

Link to apple help page: https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201559

> You should force restart your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch as a last resort, and only if it's not responding. To force restart your device, press and hold both the Sleep/Wake and Home buttons for at least ten seconds, until you see the Apple logo.

Comment: Thanks! I had not realize that a force restart happens when both buttons are pushed simultaneously. I had tried pushing the Sleep button only and it did not work.

Comment: @user25004 glad you could get your `iphone 6` working :)

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem was already covered in the question [Can't backup iPhone6 without entering PIN](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176454/cant-backup-broken-iphone-6-without-entering-pin)

> As far as I'm aware, entering the pass code is a security feature when you backup for the first time to a different iTunes/computer. You can't get around it, however its possible that Apple will be able to repair the screen without wiping the phone. Maybe even mention you haven't backed up the phone when you take it to get repaired and see if they can do anything for you
>
> --Mitchell D